# Diamond pattern using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out a diamond shape using star characters and additional characters using python. I tried a lot to get the result I wanted, but not successful. I want to write a function that receives a parameters and according to that parameter it should determine the height of the diamond shape.

For example : If the parameter is 6, the first half must have 5 lines except for the middle line. middle line is shared by both the halves. bottom half must also have 5 lines.

But the additional requirement is after first 2 lines, instead of * characters, it must have "1 # 1" in the first half and in the second half it must have "2 # 2"

For example, if the input is 6, it must produce some like below

```
      *
     ***
    1 # 1
   1  #  1
  1   #   1
 ***********
  2   ^   2
   2  ^  2
    2 ^ 2
     ***
      *
```

So, this is what I tried so far

```
def print_half_diamond(height):
    if height <= 0:
        print("Height must be a positive integer.")
        return

    for i in range(1, height + 1):
        spaces = " " * (height - i)
        line = ""

        if i == 1 or i == 2:
            line = "*" * (2 * i - 1)
        else:
            line = "1" + " " * (2 * (i - 2) + 1) + "#" + " " * (2 * (height - i)) + "1"

        print(spaces + line)

    print("*" * (2 * height - 1))

    for i in range(height - 1, 0, -1):
        spaces = " " * (height - i)
        stars = "*" * (2 * i - 1)
        print(spaces + stars)

print_half_diamond(6)
```

The first half is somewhat correct but the spacing is wrong, the second half just prints out the * characters as follows

```
    *
    ***
   1   #      1
  1     #    1
 1       #  1
1         #1
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

How do i get the result I want? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top and bottom halves of the diamond are effectively mirror images of each other. Therefore you only need to write code to format one half. The other half is just the reverse. Something like this:

```
def diamond(n):
    def rows(c, mc='#'):
        return [f'{c: >{i+2}}{mc: >{m-i-1}}{c: >{m-i-1}}' for i in range(n-3)]
    if n > 2:
        middle = '*' * (w := n * 2 - 1)
        m = w // 2
        top = [f'{"***": >{m+2}}', f'{"*": >{m+1}}']
        print(*reversed(rows('1')+top), middle, *rows('2', '^')+top, sep='\n')

diamond(6)
```

**Output:**

```
     *
    ***
   1 # 1   
  1  #  1  
 1   #   1 
***********
 2   ^   2 
  2  ^  2  
   2 ^ 2   
    ***
     *
```

Or, by using the centering format specifier...

```
def diamond(n):
    def rows(c, mc='#'):
        return [f'{e:^{w}}' for e in [f'{c}{" "*i}{mc}{" "*i}{c}' for i in range(n-3, 0, -1)] + ['***', '*']]
    if n > 2:
        w = n * 2 - 1
        print(*reversed(rows('1')), '*'*w, *rows('2', '^'), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can be made even shorter, but for now this should help you by fixing the maths...

```
def print_half_diamond(height):
    if height <= 0:
        print("Height must be a positive integer.")
        return

    for row in range(1, height):

        if row = 1:
          edge = ''
          vertical = '*'
        elif row = 2:
          edge = '*'
          vertical = '*'
        else:
          edge = '1'
          vertical = '#'
        
        pad = ' ' * (height - row)
        gap = ' ' * (row - 2)

        print(f'{pad}{edge}{gap}{vertical}{gap}{edge}')

    print("*" * (2 * height - 1))

    for row in range(height-1, 0, -1):

        if row = 1:
          edge = ''
          vertical = '*'
        elif row = 2:
          edge = '*'
          vertical = '*'
        else:
          edge = '2'
          vertical = '#'
        
        pad = ' ' * (height - row)
        gap = ' ' * (row - 2)

        print(f'{pad}{edge}{gap}{vertical}{gap}{edge}') 

print_half_diamond(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def print_diamond(height: int):
    if height <= 0:
        print('Height must be a positive integer.')
        return
    # upper half
    first_spaces = height - 1
    spaces_bw_1 = 1
    for i in range(height - 1):
        if i == 0:
            print(' '*first_spaces + '*')
            first_spaces -= 1
        elif i == 1:
            print(' '*first_spaces + '*'*3)
            first_spaces -= 1
        else:
            print(' '*first_spaces + '1' + ' '*spaces_bw_1 + '#' + ' '*spaces_bw_1 + '1')
            first_spaces -= 1
            spaces_bw_1 += 1
    # middle row
    print('*'*(height-1) + '*' + '*'*(height-1))
    # bottom half
    first_spaces = 1
    spaces_bw_2 = spaces_bw_1 - 1
    for i in range(height - 1, 0, -1):
        if i == 1:
            print(' ' * first_spaces + '*')
            first_spaces += 1
        elif i == 2:
            print(' '*first_spaces + '*' * 3)
            first_spaces += 1
        else:
            print(' '*first_spaces + '2' + ' '*spaces_bw_2 + '^' + ' '*spaces_bw_2 + '2')
            first_spaces += 1
            spaces_bw_2 -= 1


# driver program
print_diamond(6)
```